# Trouble inserting content to database, need help escaping PHP code

Tags: php, html, sql, database, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

Hey I'm having trouble inserting page content into my database.

I'm trying to store:

```
<p class=\"heading_large\"><?php echo $Topic2C2A[data]; ?></p>
```

Using this code:

```
$sql="UPDATE event SET 
  data='<p class=\"heading_large\"><?php echo $Topic2C2A[data]; ?></p>' 
  WHERE id='2'";
```

But when I look at the table all I see is:

```
<p class="heading_large"><?php echo ; ?></p>
```

I've obviously escaped the HTML with slashes, is there something similar I need to do with the PHP so `$Topic2C2A[data]` is displayed?

Comment: *Why* are you trying to store PHP code in there? Why don't you put the data in a single-quoted string variable first? Why don't you use the appropriate database escaping function?

Comment: `data='<p class=\"heading_large\">' . $Topic2C2A[data] . '</p>'` should work much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you write your $sql as:

```
$sql="UPDATE event SET data='<p class=\"heading_large\">".$Topic2C2A[data]."</p>' WHERE id='2'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to the fact PHP is processing variables inside " (double) quotes.

You can change quotes to ' (single) or another option is to change `$Topic2C2A[data]` to `\$Topic2C2A[data]`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try mysqli_real_escape_string()? It should return a fully escaped String!